# No inspect views option on my Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was just experimenting with developing a chrome extension, while I noticed the `Inspect views: background page` option disappeared off my extension in `chrome://extensions`:

[image]

Note how it shows forAdBlock, but not for my extension 'Facebook Star'. Ideas? My app does not have a window I could right click on, as it just runs in the background, so how could I see it's console and devtools?

I'm running Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 on lubuntu for all that matters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe you accidentally deleted some of the code from a "manifest.json" file

```
"background": {
   "page": "background.html"
},
```

or

```
"background": {
   "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I don't have this line included in my `manifest.json`, as I only inject content scripts.. Is this line a must?

Comment: No, but if you to see `Inspect views: background page`, you must add this lines

Comment: My `manifest.json` contains the `"background":` ... `"scripts": ["background.js"]` as shown above, but Chrome still indicates that there are "No active views" for inspecting. I'm using version 73.0.3683.75 (64-bit).

Comment: For **"manifest_version": 3** they have renamed scripts: `"background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
   },`

Answer (score 4):

Inspect views are only for background stuff that are **independent** from any chrome tab.

Since you're only using content scripts the `inspect view` equivalent is **associated with each injected tab**. You can access the sandboxed environment of the injected script by going to the console window on the injected tab then selecting the page context of your extension:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone else who ends up here trying to get "Inspect views: background page" to appear had the same problem as me: you need to have "Developer mode" turned on in the top right hand corner of the chrome://extensions pages.

(This wasn't the OP's problem, since we can see in the screenshot that they had it turned on, but this question is one of the top hits if you're trying to figure out how to get that option to appear, so I hope this might help some other people anyway!)

Answer (score 2):

Also I would like to add to the thread that you must remember to **compile and hit the "Load unpacked"** button on the top left corner every-time you make changes or you just won't see it. Also if you use page and script at the same time it will complain.

*This post might be old, and this might sound silly, but I spent some good 10 mins without realizing this...*

Answer (score 1):

For `"manifest_version": 3`, the implementation is as follows:

1. In the `manifest.json` file, add this line:

```
"background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
```

2. Create a `background.js` file in the root level of the extension folder.
3. The contents of the `background.js` file can be empty, but I used this comment

```
// This exists only to create a link to the console in chrome://extensions/
```

4. Reload the extension and you'll see a link.

In my case, it says `Inspect views service worker` and works as intended